# What's that geothermal smell?

Tags: geothermal-heat

Visit any geothermal area like Iceland, Yellowstone or Rotorua, and you notice a disgusting smell. The web-pages all discuss hydrogen sulphide, but there is something else, like burned bacon. I'm guessing some kind of sulphurous organic?

Comment: Hydrogen sulfide: eggs. Sulfur dioxide: garlic.

Comment: I know about H2S and SO2, but that's not what I'm asking. There is some other smell as well.